# Nodejs question on how to access functions

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a Nodejs basic question. Can someone guide me on how I can navigate to the below Object if I have to execute any of the functions below? I am primarily a Java developer but trying to fix something in a Nodejs application.

Example : The below is a knex object. How do I access any of the methods below? In theory I am looking to access the "queryBuilder"  within the _context object and find out what was the underlying native query used to update by the bookshelf.js orm.

```
afterUpdate: async (model, attrs, options) => {
     console.log(attrs)  
   }
```

//Printing attrs above shows the below in console.log

```
{
  transacting: [Function: knex] {
    with: [Function],
    withRecursive: [Function],
    select: [Function],
    as: [Function],
    columns: [Function],
    column: [Function],
    from: [Function],
    fromJS: [Function],
    into: [Function],
    withSchema: [Function],
    table: [Function],
    distinct: [Function],
    join: [Function],
    joinRaw: [Function],
    innerJoin: [Function],
    leftJoin: [Function],
    leftOuterJoin: [Function],
    rightJoin: [Function],
    rightOuterJoin: [Function],
    outerJoin: [Function],
    fullOuterJoin: [Function],
    crossJoin: [Function],
    where: [Function],
    andWhere: [Function],
    orWhere: [Function],
    whereNot: [Function],
    orWhereNot: [Function],
    whereRaw: [Function],
    whereWrapped: [Function],
    havingWrapped: [Function],
    orWhereRaw: [Function],
    whereExists: [Function],
    orWhereExists: [Function],
    whereNotExists: [Function],
    orWhereNotExists: [Function],
    whereIn: [Function],
    orWhereIn: [Function],
    whereNotIn: [Function],
    orWhereNotIn: [Function],
    whereNull: [Function],
    orWhereNull: [Function],
    whereNotNull: [Function],
    orWhereNotNull: [Function],
    whereBetween: [Function],
    whereNotBetween: [Function],
    andWhereBetween: [Function],
    andWhereNotBetween: [Function],
    orWhereBetween: [Function],
    orWhereNotBetween: [Function],
    groupBy: [Function],
    groupByRaw: [Function],
    orderBy: [Function],
    orderByRaw: [Function],
    union: [Function],
    unionAll: [Function],
    intersect: [Function],
    having: [Function],
    havingRaw: [Function],
    orHaving: [Function],
    orHavingRaw: [Function],
    offset: [Function],
    limit: [Function],
    count: [Function],
    countDistinct: [Function],
    min: [Function],
    max: [Function],
    sum: [Function],
    sumDistinct: [Function],
    avg: [Function],
    avgDistinct: [Function],
    increment: [Function],
    decrement: [Function],
    first: [Function],
    debug: [Function],
    pluck: [Function],
    clearSelect: [Function],
    clearWhere: [Function],
    clearOrder: [Function],
    clearHaving: [Function],
    insert: [Function],
    update: [Function],
    returning: [Function],
    del: [Function],
    delete: [Function],
    truncate: [Function],
    transacting: [Function],
    connection: [Function],
    _context: {
      queryBuilder: [Function: queryBuilder],
      raw: [Function: raw],
      batchInsert: [Function: batchInsert],
      transaction: [Function: transaction],
      transactionProvider: [Function: transactionProvider],
      initialize: [Function: initialize],
      destroy: [Function: destroy],
      ref: [Function: ref],
      disableProcessing: [Function: disableProcessing],
      enableProcessing: [Function: enableProcessing],
      withUserParams: [Function: withUserParams],
      client: [Client_PG],
      userParams: {}
    },
    raw: [Function: raw],
    batchInsert: [Function: batchInsert],
    transaction: [Function],
    transactionProvider: [Function: transactionProvider],
    initialize: [Function: initialize],
    destroy: [Function: destroy],
    ref: [Function: ref],
    withUserParams: [Function],
    queryBuilder: [Function: queryBuilder],
    disableProcessing: [Function: disableProcessing],
    enableProcessing: [Function: enableProcessing],
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
    _eventsCount: 0,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    setMaxListeners: [Function: setMaxListeners],
    getMaxListeners: [Function: getMaxListeners],
    emit: [Function: emit],
    addListener: [Function: addListener],
    on: [Function: addListener],
    prependListener: [Function: prependListener],
    once: [Function: once],
    prependOnceListener: [Function: prependOnceListener],
    removeListener: [Function: removeListener],
    off: [Function: removeListener],
    removeAllListeners: [Function: removeAllListeners],
    listeners: [Function: listeners],
    rawListeners: [Function: rawListeners],
    listenerCount: [Function: listenerCount],
    eventNames: [Function: eventNames],
    _internalListeners: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    isTransaction: true,
    savepoint: [Function],
    commit: [Function],
    rollback: [Function],
    isCompleted: [Function],
    executionPromise: Promise [Object] {
      _bitField: 1,
      _fulfillmentHandler0: [Function: finallyHandler],
      _rejectionHandler0: [Function: finallyHandler],
      _promise0: [Promise [Object]],
      _receiver0: [PassThroughHandlerContext]
    }
  },
  method: 'update',
  patch: true,
  silent: true,
  query: Builder {
    client: Client_PG {
      version: '10.12,',
      config: [Object],
      driver: [PG],
      connectionSettings: [Object],
      transacting: true,
      valueForUndefined: [Raw],
      logger: [Logger],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 4,
      query: [Function],
      stream: [Function],
      acquireConnection: [Function],
      releaseConnection: [Function],
      makeKnex: [Function: makeKnex]
    },
    and: [Circular],
    _single: { table: 'pages', only: false, returning: '*', update: [Object] },
    _statements: [ [Object] ],
    _method: 'update',
    _debug: false,
    _joinFlag: 'inner',
    _boolFlag: 'and',
    _notFlag: false,
    _asColumnFlag: false,
    _events: [Object: null prototype] { query: [Function] },
    _eventsCount: 1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In NodeJS (actually in EcmaScript and JavaScript) functions are values just like any other type (of course they have a different behavior).

So you can access any field of type function and execute it simply adding parentheses at the end.

If `transacting` is the function you want to call, you can simply do `attrs.transacting(...)`.
Altough I think in your example you want to call a sub-member inside this function. So, at the same time, functions can have also other attributes that can be at the same time other functions, so you could call `attrs.transacting.select(...)`.

Besides that, functions in EcmaScript/JavaScript can be also constructors. If your function is a constructor (to create new objects with its own scope and reference to `this`), just add the `new` keyword ahead.

Hope this helps. Any doubt don't hesitate in asking for a clarification in my answer.

Comment: Do you mean something like this?   let x =  attrs.transaction(...) . This gives a compile error. If I do attrs.transaction() it says attrs is not defined.

Comment: As per your console.log output, the name of the field is 'transacting', not 'transaction'. Please try with that. Even so, you probably may not call that directly, depending of what is that object (I guess it is something provided by a database package or so). But anyway the compiler error is about the incorrect field name.